# Add Button to Non Client Area in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, nonclient-area

A follow up to my [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53893146/add-items-to-the-window-chrome-of-a-windows-forms-application?noredirect=1#comment94634167_53893146) on adding a button to the Window Chrome (also known as the `Non Client Area`) in `Windows Forms`, I have decided to switch to `WPF` to have a better chance of solving my issue. I need to add some buttons to the `Non Client Area` or Window Chrome similar to that of Firefox 4

[image: Example]

From what I have heard it is easier to do this in WPF. I have no idea where to start. If possible could someone give me some guidance on how to do this?

Comment: Maybe it is too late but did you find what you were looking for. I am now trying to achieve the exact same thing as I need to customize the titlebar header of `Window` but keep the rest as is. Most of the stuffs online are either customizing only the control template or are changing the close minimize maximise buttons as well. Any pointers would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the Window Control Template.  See examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/window-styles-and-templates?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: Hi, I have been messing around with Control Template and I would like to know how I can keep the default look of the `Non Client Area` but add a button.

Comment: When customizing the template of `Window` I can only change the visual representation of the client area. I would like to add a content control or any other controls to the title bar and keep the rest of the look as is.

Comment: @ProudAviatior, I am afraid the current approach is "all or nothing".  I think the same applies for Win32 apps.